# Adding Python libraries to remote cluster machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, lua

I'm trying to run a Python script on a remote machine that is a node for a Spark cluster. I have 0 rights on this machine beyond a little home folder for myself, but to run my script I need two libraries (`networkx` and `shapely`).

As my issue is solely with the imports, I am currently trying to run a basic `wordcount` script but importing the libraries I will need for my final project.

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

def calculate(sc):
    text_file = sc.textFile("nevergonnagive.txt")
    counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
                 .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
                 .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
    counts.saveAsTextFile("word_count_OUT")
    return sc

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

conf_spark = SparkConf()

conf_spark.set('spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH','~/local/lib/:/usr/bin/python3.6')
conf_spark.set('spark.executorEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH','~/local/lib/python3.6: /some/path/Python/3.7.2/lib')

import itertools
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.connectivity import local_edge_connectivity
import random
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

sc=calculate(sc)
sc.close()
```

I copied my `/usr/lib/python3.6/` folder from my local machine (Linux Mint 19) to the node (Red Hat 7) in `~/local/lib/python3.6` - all of my libraries are now in `~/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/`, including the two I need.

I can temporarily change environment variables, and load `.lua` modules (which I have no experience with). Some modules already exist on this node in `/usr/lib/modules`:

```
$ module show python/3.6.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   /some/path/modulefiles/python/3.6.5.lua:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
help([[Interpréteur Python
Version disponible sous rh7
]])
whatis("Nom     : Python")
whatis("Version : 3.6.5")
whatis("Os      : rh7")
whatis("Date d installation : 14/08/2019")
setenv("PYTHON_HOME","/some/path/Python/3.6.5")
prepend_path("PATH","/some/path/Python/3.6.5/bin")
prepend_path("LD_LIBRARY_PATH","/some/path/Python/3.6.5/lib")
prepend_path("MANPATH","/some/path/Python/3.6.5/share/man")
prepend_path("PKG_CONFIG_PATH","/some/path/Python/3.6.5/lib/pkgconfig")
setenv("PIP_CERT","/some/path/certs/ca-bundle.crt")
```

I tried creating a similar file to this in my home folder to import the `networkx` library, but running `module load networkx/2.4` did not work, it could not find the file, and I cannot modify anything in `/usr/lib/` or in `/some/path/modulefiles/`.

In another attempt, I added the following lines to my script:

```
conf_spark.set('spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH','~/local/lib/:/usr/bin/python3.6')
conf_spark.set('spark.executorEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH','~/local/lib/python3.6: /some/path/Python/3.7.2/lib')
```

But this did not work.

Virtual environments are out of the question because of the clustering.

Can I force module to look in my local directory? Can I force the file path of my libraries?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, u have access to only one node of spark cluster.
The right way to do it, it is to open shared mount on all the executors, than copy your venv into the mount, and add --conf spark.pyspark.python=/path/to/venv.

because you dont have premission for that, the only way you can do it (when you run on the cluster, and not on local mode) - is to make a zip from your site-packages folder(e.g dep.zip), than when you submit a job (via spark-submit) add --py-files.

I dont recommend you to do that, becuase with my experiment using --pyfiles dep.zip will not work properly when u have C compiled libraries (e.g numpy,pymssql...).